# what determines the rule precedence in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, rules

I have created rules for the Task work item type, that when certain conditions are matched, a field should be required, otherwise the field should be cleared and made read-only.

I cannot get the same behaviour work on the Test Case work item. If the rule for making the field read-only is not disabled, then the field is made read-only, but retains its value. If the rule for making the field read-only is disabled, then the field value is cleared, but anyone can write in it.

every combination of rule conditions and actions I could think of

n/a

Expected results: rules work the same way for the test case work item type as for the Task WIT

Comment: Could you provide the conditions and actions of the rule you set?

Comment: rule #1
condition: area ID equals 16
action: set the value of shadowareaid to 16

rule #2
condition: area ID does not equal 16
actions: clear value of crossfunctional and set the value of shadowareaid to 0

rule #3
condition: shadowareaid equals 16
action: make crossfunctional read-only

Answer (score 0):

According to the rule settings you provided and your demand in the case: 
**the field should be cleared and made read-only**
, so rule#2 and rule#3 should be triggered.

But when rule#2 is in effect, the value of shadowareaid should be 0, and the condition for rule#3 to take effect is that the value of shadowareaid should be equal to 16. There is a conflict between the two rules. If you want rule#3 to take effect, you need to change the value of shadowareaid to 16, and you break rule#2 as well.

If you want both rules to take effect, you need to modify the rules settings to avoid conflicts.

Comment: apologies, rule #3's condition is shadowareaid does not equal 16, I made a mistake when typing the rules properties in my previous comment, but the issue is there with the correct settings

Comment: I can reproduce your issue here.This look like a bug,try to create an issue here:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21  Attach the rule setting to your issue. If it is confirmed as a bug, the product team will fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I just submitted it:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/658124/work-item-type-rule-ignored.html